# How can i start main Activity from my soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, keyboard

I have MainActivity - "Activity" and Service - "Keyboard", when locate my Soft Keyboard.

How can i start my Activity, where i press Key "Hint" on my Soft Keyboard.

Example:

```
private void Hint_key(int keyEventCode) {

}
```

Comment: do you hace access to `Context` in the class where you've defined `Hint_key`? Perhaps put your full code for this class

Comment: Yes, i have access to Context - Tnanks! But i am have new problem... I want my application to cause the keyboard (a small window with the help text). Is it possible?

Comment: Can't you identify the key code on press and initiate the desired activity through context?

Comment: No, i called main activity in new window, but i`m want call my main Activity into soft keyboard

Comment: You want start Activity from Service?

Comment: yes. I want start Android Activity from Service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want start Activity from Service, do next:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(intent);
```